# How to enumerate all HID devices? C#

Tags: c#, .net, usb, hid

I need to enumerate all HID devices connected to my PC. I tried to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331509/902424), but it enumerates USBHub devices and I can't find there my HID device.

**EDIT**:
I will be glad to know If there any WIN32 API method, to get USB device status (online/offline) using PID and VID?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3738842/735446

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft's WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) has documentation for the HID functions and an overview of how to use them. The WDK also includes the header files to use with Visual C++ programs that access HID-class devices (hidsdi.h, hidusage.h, hidpi.h).

Check this link [Jan Axelson's Lakeview Research - HID Windows Programming.](http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm)

Here is an question also available regarding HID devices as you specified in your question:
[Scanning for a Human Interface Device (HID) using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729970/scanning-for-a-human-interface-device-hid-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/GetHardwareInformation.aspx) explains how to do this with `ManagementObjectSearcher`.

Thanks for all who replied!

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate Hid devices with Windows APIs like this:

```
        public static Collection<DeviceInformation> GetConnectedDeviceInformations()
        {
            var deviceInformations = new Collection<DeviceInformation>();
            var spDeviceInterfaceData = new SpDeviceInterfaceData();
            var spDeviceInfoData = new SpDeviceInfoData();
            var spDeviceInterfaceDetailData = new SpDeviceInterfaceDetailData();
            spDeviceInterfaceData.CbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(spDeviceInterfaceData);
            spDeviceInfoData.CbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(spDeviceInfoData);

            var hidGuid = new Guid();

            APICalls.HidD_GetHidGuid(ref hidGuid);

            var i = APICalls.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref hidGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.DigcfDeviceinterface | APICalls.DigcfPresent);

            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
            {
                spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.CbSize = 8;
            }
            else
            {
                spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.CbSize = 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize;
            }

            var x = -1;

            while (true)
            {
                x++;

                var setupDiEnumDeviceInterfacesResult = APICalls.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(i, IntPtr.Zero, ref hidGuid, (uint)x, ref spDeviceInterfaceData);
                var errorNumber = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                //TODO: deal with error numbers. Give a meaningful error message

                if (setupDiEnumDeviceInterfacesResult == false)
                {
                    break;
                }

                APICalls.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(i, ref spDeviceInterfaceData, ref spDeviceInterfaceDetailData, 256, out _, ref spDeviceInfoData);

                var deviceInformation = GetDeviceInformation(spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.DevicePath);
                if (deviceInformation == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                deviceInformations.Add(deviceInformation);
            }

            APICalls.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(i);

            return deviceInformations;
}
```

Full class: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net/Windows/WindowsHIDDevice.cs

APIS: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net/Windows/APICalls.cs

Comment: The links seem to be dead.