# C#.NET How to find a list of ManagementObjectSearcher array element

Tags: c#

Here is my code, I have copied from one of your question and the code is :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI","SELECT * FROM MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames");


            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                //Console.WriteLine("MSWmi_PnPInstanceNames instance");
                //Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]);

            }

            Console.Read();

        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, my question is : what is the element of queryObj array ?

Comment: Don't you have a compiler?

Comment: `queryObj` isn't an array - it's a `ManagementObject`.

Comment: The first hit on google, when you search for `ManagementObject`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.management.managementobject.aspx

Comment: queryObj contains info about HID(Humaman Interface Device).http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729970/scanning-for-a-human-interface-device-hid-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

[`ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67a77ef1.aspx) method return type is [`ManagementObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.aspx).

The objects in this collection are of *ManagementBaseObject-derived* types, including [`ManagementObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ManagementClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.aspx).

From `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()` method;

> Invokes the specified WMI query and returns the resulting collection.

`InstanceName` is `proopertyName` for instance of `ManagementObject` which returns from `ManagementObjectSearcher.Get` method.

Comment: Thanks @Soner 
I'm using Visual Studio 2010, How can I get my HID device name ??

Comment: @MarufHossain You are welcome `;)` Check out this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354700/how-to-enumerate-all-hid-devices-c-sharp